# PhoneGap - read datas beyond the app-folder

Tags: android, file, cordova, root

is it possible to read xml files (Android OS) for example in the root (/system/data/...)?

A native app needs a rooted phone and superuser rights.
Can I give that rights to a PhoneGap-App?
Or is it only possible to work in a sandbox while using PhoneGap?